# What causes my question to be advertised on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

It was so weird seeing this ad after being the author of the question only yesterday. [image]

This got me curious. How often are these ads generated and circulated? Are they automated by the SE network, or do moderators suggest them? My question hit the hot-bar and therefore got attention, but I dont know if you'd consider it worthy of introducing new people to the site.

Comment: One word: 'magic!'.

Comment: Otherwise you can look [this on meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

Answer (score 2):

That's generated by "Hot Network Questions" filter, which is automatic and based on vague criteria.

It also has a mostly-deserved reputation for publicizing questions that are actually very inappropriate for the parent sites.

Comment: Was mine appropriate by your standards btw? Im new here, and not very familiar with what you consider good questions.

Comment: @Viziionary It's fine. I probably would have voted to close it, _personally_ (I think it's a bit borderline), but since my votes are unilateral and binding I didn't.